# JPA Index specification on substring

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, substring

I'd like to define such an index: `create index annuaire_abc_substr_idx on annuaire(substring(abc,7,2));`

Whith JPA Specification I'd like to write something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "annuaire", 
    indexes = {
            @Index(name = "annuaire_abc_substr_idx", columnList = "???")
    }
)
```

Is there a way to use this javax.persistence.Index annotation to work with a substring?